# PHP discount code for simple shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty novice at PHP/MySQL and have been following a tutorial for a simple shopping cart which I've managed to get up and running but I'm now trying to make a few changes and having some difficulty finding the solution.

Is it possible to add a simple discount option of 10% to the following code. Basically just a textbox with Apply button next to it, then when the user enters a discount code of 'loyalty10'. The cart updates to give 10% off the total amount with a line through the original amount.

view_cart.php

```
    <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
<table width="100%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th>Remove</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) 
    {
        $total = 0; 
        $b = 0;  
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
            $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
            $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
            $product_price = $cart_itm["price"];
            $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
            $product_weight = $cart_itm["weight"];
            $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); 

            $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; 
            echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
            echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$currency.$product_price.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$currency.$subtotal.'</td>';
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);
        }

        $grand_total = $total + $shipping_cost; 
        foreach($taxes as $key => $value){ 
                $tax_amount     = round($total * ($value / 100));
                $tax_item[$key] = $tax_amount;
                $grand_total    = $grand_total + $tax_amount;  
        }

        $list_tax       = '';
        foreach($tax_item as $key => $value){ 
            $list_tax .= $key. ' : '. $currency. sprintf("%01.2f", $value).'<br />';
        }
        $shipping_cost = ($shipping_cost)?'Shipping Cost : '.$currency. sprintf("%01.2f", $shipping_cost).'<br />':'';
    }
    ?>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><span style="float:right;text-align: right;"><?php echo $shipping_cost. $list_tax; ?>Amount Payable : <?php echo sprintf("%01.2f", $grand_total);?></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="5"><a href="index.php" class="button">Add More Items</a><button type="submit">Update</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php 
$current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $current_url; ?>" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: your code seems incomplete as it has an error and some variables were never set before they are used in your code.

to achieve what you want you need to:

- add an input field to your form 
  `<input type="text" name="discount" />`
- create a `$discount` variable that has the value of `false`
- check in your code if (I assume POST) `$_POST['discount']` is set and if it has your discount code `isset($_POST['discount']) && $_POST['discount']=="loyalty10"`
- set `$discount` to `true`
- when displaying your sum add add a condition

  ```
  if($discount){
  <tr><td colspan="5"><span style="float:right;text-align: right;"><?php echo $shipping_cost. $list_tax; ?>Amount Payable : <s><?php echo sprintf("%01.2f", $grand_total);?></s></span></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="5"><span style="float:right;text-align: right;">Amount Payable : <?php echo sprintf("%01.2f", $grand_total * 0.9);?></span></td></tr>
  <?php }else{ ?>
   <tr><td colspan="5"><span style="float:right;text-align: right;"><?php echo $shipping_cost. $list_tax; ?>Amount Payable : <?php echo sprintf("%01.2f", $grand_total);?></span></td></tr>
  <?php } ?>
  ```

There are better and cleaner ways to do this. You could use a css class instead of html elements for example

Answer (score 0):

use ajax for checking your promo-code is correct or not without reloading the whole page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitbuttonid").click(function(){
    var discount=$.trim($("#discountfeildid").val());
    $.ajax({
    url:"page.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{discount:discount},
    cache:false,
    success:function(data){ 
    if(data){
$("#wherepriceisbeingshowID").load(location.href + " #wherepriceisbeingshowID");  
    } 
    }
    error:function(){
    alert('An Error Occured');
    }  
    });
    });

    });
```

Create a page.php

```
if(isset($_POST['discount'])){

  if($_POST['discount']=='your discount code'){
//reset your cart total amount
//return some data
}
}
```

Hope this will help you.